# PHP error on deploying to heroku

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

I am new in deploying PHP application on Heroku. My app is working fine locally but on heroku it is giving error shown in the image. It is written in CodeIgniter framework.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In your [system/core/Common.php](https://github.com/mit456/resistance/blob/master/system/core/Common.php), modify line 257 to -

```
$_config[0] =& $config;
return $_config[0];
```

Further reading - https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/244510/#1066393

Answer (score 0):

In index.php please check your setting or place this code there.

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');  

error_reporting(0);
if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
        switch (ENVIRONMENT)
        {
            case 'development':
                //error_reporting(E_ALL);
            break;

            case 'testing':
            case 'production':
                //error_reporting(0);
            break;

            default:
                exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
        }
  }
```

Comment: can you please check this line "error_reporting(0);"

Comment: can you please check my code and can you kindly tell me how to integrate with heroku?? [Here](https://github.com/mit456/resistance.git) is the link.